# Hidden header from stack-navigation go to statusbar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm new at React-nativ. And I cant solve problem.When I tried to hide a stack-navigator header and use :

```
 Home :{
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerShown: false,
            title: 'NO TITLE'

        }
    }
```

and after this content of **Home**, which is a simple Text inside View  go to statusbar.
[image]
I think that is only CSS problem but i dont understand how it fix. I attach my code below.

App.js :

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
//import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Navigator from './routes/homeStack'

export default function App() {
  return (

    <Navigator />
  );
}
```

homeStack.js :

```
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack'
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'
import Home from '../components/Home'
import ReviewDetails from '../components/ReviewDetails'

const screens = {
    Home :{
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerShown: false,
            title: 'NO TITLE'

        }
    },
    ReviewDetails :{
        screen: ReviewDetails
    }

}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens);

export default createAppContainer(HomeStack);
```

Home.js :

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { TextInput, View, Button, Text } from 'react-native' 

const Home = props => {

    const [enteredGoal,setEnteredGoal] = useState('');

    const  goalInputHandler = (enteredText) => {
        setEnteredGoal(enteredText);
    }

    return(
        <View >
            <Text>HOME PAGE</Text>
        </View>
    )
}



export default Home;
```

I understand that solve of this problem is add a padding to content but for me it hotfix not a bugfix. How to say for app dont use a space of Android statusbar.

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```js
let HomeStack=createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home:Home
    },
    {
        initialRouteName:'Home',
        headerMode:'none'
    })
```

where headerMode:'none' is what your looking for

Comment: like my variant works as your. the problem is that content showed in statusbar. it looks like that content of app that no reserve space for statusbar at top of the screnn.

Comment: I think your problem is in the Home component can you show it

Comment: use SafeAreaView (from react-native module)instead of View

Answer (score 0):

Use SafeAreaView in component.